# TFSReports account

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-reports

We are getting started to use TFS in our company, but I am having some issue with our IT-department.

The TFSReports account is a service account, and thus the IT guy will not allow Local logon, because it is service account. Not sure if he is right, but what other options do I have?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Daniel's answer below? any update?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way around that -- it's listed as a requirement because it's a requirement.

You can consider *not* setting up reporting services; a lot of the newer features in the past 3-5 years aren't stored in the data warehouse or analysis cubes (builds and releases, as a major example) because the push has been to make the reporting capabilities in TFS itself as good or better than what's stored reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation here: [Service accounts and dependencies in Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/service-accounts-dependencies-tfs)

> TFSReports, which can be a local account, a domain account, or Local Service in a workgroup.
>
> Required Permission and Group Membership: Allow log on locally on the application-tier server and on the server that is running SQL Server Reporting Services
> TFSWareHouseDataReader on the report server

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.